# How can I avoid tilda from creating a new configuration file each time it is lauched

Tags: configure, tilda

Everytime I lauch Tilda, a new configuration file is used and I have to do the configuration again.

```
$ ls
config_0  config_1
```

How can I prevent Tilda from creating a new con

Comment: How do you invoke `tilda`?

Comment: From a non-root user through the gnome-interface.

Comment: You mean you click on a shortcut?

Comment: yes, in the applications menu.

Comment: Check the shortcut, should be located in `/usr/share/applications`, look for `tilda.desktop`, otherwise do a file-search to find it, open it in editor to check the command.

Comment: Look for this line:`Exec=/usr/bin/tilda`

Comment: The name of the file is `/usr/share/applications/Tilda` This is the shortcut on my system.

Comment: The only `tilda.desktop` I have is `usr/share/applications` and has the entry `Exec=/usr/bin/tilda`. Lauching `/usr/bin/tilda` creates a new configuration file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46172/discussion-between-mook765-and-wcg).

Answer (score 1):

/home/user/.config/tilda/ had the wrong permission

```
chmod a+rwx /home/user/.config/tilda
```